# video merging ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video

A client of mine wants an app with the following functionality:

They send me a video and information on timeframes when a user can interact with video.

When the timeframe comes , the video has a white screen (already in there) and i switch video output to the camera. Then the user does some talking to the (recording) camera till the timeframe is over , then it switches back to the video.

This happens for about 5 timeframes in a 2 minute video ( timeframes and videos are variable)

After the entire video is played and everything is recorded, i need to merge the existing video with the recorded videos ( put the recorded videos on the specified timeframes)  and 'compile' it as a new video.

Since i've never worked with video on iOS i'm asking for some help/directions.  I've already  checked out **AVFoundation**, but it hasn't made me wiser whether this is possible or how to do it.